Offset does not work when I try to apply the range to multiple columns
I have an R1C1 formula with Row Offset that works correctly when I only use one column (Test Formula).
RowNum3 = Worksheets("TimePhase Dollars").Range("C1048576").End(xlUp).Row

'Test Formula 
Worksheets("Timephase Dollars").Range("I" & RowNum3).Offset(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(Year(R1C)=2024,Vlookup(RC6,look,9,false),0)*'TimePhase Hours'!RC[-2]"

When I try to apply the formula to a Range of Columns it doesn't populate anything.  If I remove the Offset function, the formula populates.  I'm sure it's probably something simple but I can't figure it out. (Test Formula2)
'Test Formula2 
Worksheets("Timephase Dollars").Range("I:Z" & RowNum3).Offset(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(Year(R1C)=2024,Vlookup(RC6,look,9,false),0)*'TimePhase Hours'!RC[-2]"

Any help is appreciated!
I also tried naming the range of columns and using a named range but no luck.

Range("I" & RowNum3 & ":Z" & RowNum3).Offset(1) or Range("I1:Z1").Offset(RowNum3)

Or even: Range("I:Z").Rows(rownum3 + 1).FormulaR1C1
